# Solr fails to serve JSPs, admin interface 404s

Tags: solr, jetty, java

I'm having trouble with solr. I'm running it on Ubuntu with OpenJDK:

```
>> java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

The admin interface should be served by Jetty 7, which is installed in the solr/example folder according to these instructions: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty#Update_Jetty

On starting solr with 'start.jar' I see the following:

```
>> java -jar
2012-05-21 14:03:01.121:WARN:oejd.ContextDeployer:ContextDeployer is deprecated. Use ContextProvider
2012-05-21 14:03:01.126:WARN:oejd.WebAppDeployer:WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider
```

...at which point the process ends.

If I instead use 'jetty7.jar', solr starts and runs, but on attempting to access the admin interface at localhost:8983/solr/ I see the following:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Servlet Not Initialized
Caused by:

javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet Not Initialized
```

The output on the command line is the following:

```
>> java -jar jetty7.jar 
2012-05-21 14:03:01.121:WARN:oejd.ContextDeployer:ContextDeployer is deprecated. Use ContextProvider
2012-05-21 14:03:01.126:WARN:oejd.WebAppDeployer:WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider
2012-05-21 14:03:01.129:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.3.v20120416
2012-05-21 14:03:01.238:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/var/lib/solr/apache-solr-3.6.0/example/webapps/solr.war!/ to /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8983-solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp
2012-05-21 14:03:02.518:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2012-05-21 14:03:02.565:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8983-solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp/},file:/var/lib/solr/apache-solr-3.6.0/example/webapps/solr.war
May 21, 2012 2:03:02 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader locateSolrHome
INFO: JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
```

I assume that the "NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet" line is the culprit.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually cracked it: I realized I had not copied start.ini along with start.jar from the jetty folder and there was some needed configuration in there.

Comment: can you be more specific?